# How to send an Array of Jsons in postman with Form-data

Tags: postman, joi

I'm trying to consume an API that uses the following Joi validation:

```
Joi.object({
    files: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        fileId: Joi.string().uuid().required(),
    })),
    folders: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
        folderId: Joi.string().uuid().required(),
    }))
})
```

The joi validation also requires me to send it as a FormData. I have tried a few different things, but no matter what I try I only get to send an array of strings like so:

> files: ["fileId: f28019d7-9268-4013-bacb-67ed96eb095f", "fileId: 51e99e3d-755a-4530-9eed-f08d20cbfe8b"]

[image]

So how can I send it with postman?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `form` try using raw field as below and choose type as `json`

[image]

Comment: Unsupported Media Type. There's a validation to only allow multipart/form-data.

Comment: Can you make the same request as above with a new header in `headers` tab as follows `Content-Type` : `multipart/form-data`. Please try this and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can send  array in body like this :

[image]

Comment: I just edited the question, I think I wasn't clear I need it to be Form-Data

Answer (score 0):

You can give the following values in Bulk Edit using Postman:

```
files[1]:f28019d7-9268-4013-bacb-67ed96eb095f
files[2]:51e99e3d-755a-4530-9eed-f08d20cbfe8b
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are trying to send string instead of Object:

> files: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
> fileId: Joi.string().uuid().required(),
> }))

Here you are trying to set fileId as a key in an object (inside `files` array). So what you want is `[{ fileId: "xyz" }]`.

To achieve this, you can simply **stringify** your array data. Then send in the form-data body.

```
let arr = [{ fileId: "xyz" }];
JSON.stringify(arr); // outputs in console -> "[{"fileId":"xyz"}]"
```

In Postman, you can then send the array as:

```
files:[{"fileId":"xyz"},{"fileId":"abc"}]
```

(Do this by using bulk-upload so that there are no issues like extra spaces)

[image]